# What is the procedure to follow for a north american doctor to practice in Colombia?

Tags: practice-of-medicine, health-education, different-national-health

I would like to know the requirements and procedures to follow for a Canadian doctor to practice in latin america, specifically in Colombia. For instance, are there board exams to pass? Is there a residency/social service to complete? Is the Canadian M.D. title recognized?

Thank you.